# Saving values upon excel cell deletion

Tags: vba, excel

So, I'm back with a more specific answer/problem.
Also, I'm sorry, I picked up excel (hadn't actually used the program) a few weeks back only and minimal usage. So if the code is bad/explanations unclear, comment and i'll do my best to get this together.

I am currently in a situation with two separate (albeit linked) excel files. 
Src (Book1)
Dest (Book2)
They each have one worksheet.

The idea is that Src will be modified (including deletion and insertion of rows) and i need these changes to be reflected onto Dest.

I have the insertion so far, scrounged up a little bit of code using Before_DoubleClick.

However i am having a few issues on deletion.

What i have this far is :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const destBook As String = "Book2"
    Const destSheet As String = "Sheet2"
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks(destBook)
    ' Here is the main problem i have. I need a better way to detect  
    ' deletion of one or more rows. Otherwise the Application.Undo 
    ' re-enters the if and it just loops.
    If Target.Address = Target.EntireRow.Address Then
        ' Here i Undo the deletion to be able to copy the values.
        Application.Undo
        Target.Copy
        ' I also haven't found a way to delete again but google can help me on that
        ' Pasting line
        'wb1.Sheets(destSheet).Cells(Target.Row, 1).PasteSpecial   Paste:=xlPastValues
    End If
 End Sub
```

Ideally, what should happen is, upon deletion of one or more rows, i would like to undo the last action, copy the data, delete the row and finally past the data in another worksheet. However, as of now i am blocked at undoing the last action. It calls my VBA macro again and just starts looping.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and what have you tried so far? You can use the worksheetchange event but this will trigger once the line has been deleted, so your first hurdle is to be able to determine what line/value was deleted. My suggestion is on a change to the worksheet, use the undolist control to detect it being a deletion. I'm not sure if you get the target address from the undo list, but you can do 1 undo to find cell and/or value, and then search in fileLinked for that cell reference or value and delete corresponding rows from both tables. Cheers,

Comment: Alternatively you can just trigger on worksheetchange in fileSrc and search for any #REF using .find in fileLinked and delete corresponding rows. This assumes though that any #REF relates to that reference being deleted.

Comment: @nbayly added in an edit, and thanks for the undolist tip. I'll start looking into that too but i would love it if there was a simpler way. (Similiar to a afterDoubleCLick event. but more like a uponDeletion event.)

Comment: I believe that once things get this tricky, it's time to consider controlling activity and handling events through user forms or activex objects. You can more easily capture activity in this manner and act in a corresponding manner. Can you create such a solution?

Comment: I probably could if i dive into it and put the rest of work aside.. The question is, is it worth the time i'm going to spend trying to put this together? Probably not. I'll try with a mix of worksheetchange + undoing/deactivating automatic calculation. If that works i'll post the answer.

Comment: Like I mentioned on my second comment, if you want to reach the low hanging fruit then don't even worry about the undolist. On worksheet change on fileSrc have the macro set a range on fileLinked using `Set rngError = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)` and delete all rows on that range with `rngError.EntireRow.Delete`. You might be sacrificing performance by triggering on any change in source file but likely won't be noticeable. Cheers,

Comment: @nbayly thanks for the info, will look into it and try to figure it out to do exactly what i want then i'll post the answer. (If i manage.)

Comment: Wait... misread that entirely. The idea isnt deleting the cells in fileLinked. It's keeping the last valid value the link destination had in fileLinked when the link destination (A cell from fileSrc) is deleted. So your solution doesn't help me unless i'm misunderstanding again @nbayly

Comment: No, your right. My second solution wouldn't work then. My apologies for my misunderstanding. I will try over the weekend to cobble something similar to my first suggestion if you haven't found a solution yourself. Cheers,

Comment: @nbayly I appreciate the help a lot, but don't go on overexerting yourself for nothing. It'll probably end up in a edit of my post or total deletion and creation of a new question. More specific. (And with whatever i tried as code linked.)

Comment: @nbayly Actually cross it off altogether for you. I already think i got at least a few ideas that put me on a better path. If i can figure it out, good, otherwise i will post my attempt in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you want but you either have to replace formulas with values in the new cells, or if those cells are supposed to have a formula you probably have to do

application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual

make the deletion or change then

application.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic

to turn autocalculation back on

Manual is tricky because if code crashed you would want to make sure you didn't leave the sheet in a state that didn't calculate

Comment: I'm trying to make it so the cells linked to others do not have #REF! in them and actually keep their oldest value. So actually replacing the links by their values upon deletion of a source cell